# How do i stop else looping and make it all start all over again?

Tags: python, calculator

It's like my second week of code learning and today i've found out that this is a good site for beginners to ask simple questions, so excuse me if i'm doing something wrong here.

Anyways, i decided to make my own calculator in python without google searching and here's what i've done:

```
choice = input("Enter choice: '+', '-', '/', 'x': ")
while True:
    if choice in ("+", "-", "/", "x"):
        num1 = input("First number: ")
        num2 = input("Second number: ")
        if choice == "+":
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", int(num1)+int(num2))
        elif choice == "-":
            print(num1, "-", num2, "=", int(num1)-int(num2))
        elif choice == "/":
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", int(num1)/int(num2))
        elif choice == "x":
            print(num1, "x", num2, "=", int(num1)*int(num2))
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

When i try to write letters instead of "+,-,/,x" the else statement "Invalid" keeps looping.
How do i get it to get showed only once and restart my "calculator" from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the statement `choice = input("Enter choice: '+', '-', '/', 'x': ")` inside the loop, as in:

```py
while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice: '+', '-', '/', 'x': ")
    #etc..
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I knew it would be something really obvious, because i'm really a noob.
Have a good day.

Comment: Sure @Knownothing, please mark this as solved if it helped you :D